# How to always show buffer in the new created frame?

Tags: org-mode, buffers, frames, emacsclient, ido

My workflow is:

- I initialize emacs with a shortcut (in my `~/.i3/config` I have a line like this `bindcode $mod+49 exec emacsclient -c -n -q -a=''`. I use i3wm.org)
- By default it goes to `temp.org`, in .emacs is `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/org/temp.org")`, which is useful to do temp notes
- But sometimes I want to edit an existing file, I use `C-x C-f` (`(ido-mode 1)`
   is enabled in `.emacs`), most of them, org files. I have very *large* (at least for me) org files that are part of my personal documentation. I can open the same file different times, when this happen I would like to have (and initialize) the same buffer in different frames (I see this as a good default behavior), but I never cannot do that, what happens is that switches (reuses) to the frame where the buffer is.

  - Example of my problem.

    - Given: Frame1-temp.org Frame2-thing.org
    - Action: in Frame1 I do `C-x C-f thing.org`
    - Consequence: focus switches from Frame1 to Frame2 (because there is thing.org)
    - Result: Frame1-temp.org Frame2-thing.org
  - Example of what I would like.

    - Given: Frame1-temp.org Frame2-thing.org
    - Action: in Frame1 I do `C-x C-f thing.org`
    - Consequence: Frame1 displays thing.org
    - Result: Frame1-thing.org Frame2-thing.org

Applying over and over this workflow I end up with lots of `temp.org` emacs frames opened, that I close using a bash alias: `alias killtemp='i3-msg [title="^temp.org.*"] kill'`

emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.11)
 of 2019-05-27

Comment: You might want to set `ido-default-buffer-method` to `'selected-window`, which you can do with `(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)` in your init file.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, I used an `.emacs` only with `(ido-mode 1)` and `(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)` but it switched frame :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working

```
(setq ido-default-file-method 'selected-window)
```

not working

```
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)
```

[thanks to this link](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/emacs_ido_switch_window.html), but they point to the wrong solution

works in selfcompiled [1] GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.5)
 of 2019-10-20

[1]

```
sudo apt build-dep emacs
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git
cd emacs
git checkout emacs-26.3
./autogen.sh all
./configure
make clean
make
sudo make install
```